# Regex to extract groups like 12 X 4321 from a string typically like "12X4321"

Tags: excel, regex, vba

I want to extract three groups of identifiers from WBS numbers.

Examples:

```
12B4321, 11.X.1111, M.O085C.11.X.1111,  M.O085C.11.X.1111.D2, M.O085C.23.B.0004.D2, M.O085C.23.BX.0004.D2, M.O053C.7I.F.0053.D2, M.O053C.8D.S.0001.D2, M.O053C.8I.S.0009.D2, M.O053C.8I.S.0009.D2"
```

My pattern:

```
(\d{2})([a-zA-Z])(\d{4})|(\d[a-zA-Z])\.?([a-zA-Z])\.?(\d{4})|(\d{2})\.?([a-zA-Z])\.?(\d{4})
```

When I test the pattern in Regex101, it works.
In VBA, the first example fails.

After I get the different string parts, I combine them to the form "12.B.4321" which I use in a query.

Example code:

```vb
Private Sub WBStest()
    Dim regEx As Object
    Dim WBSParts() As String
    Dim Inputstr() As String
    Dim SStr As String

    Inputstr = Split("12X4321, 13.X.6945, M.O085C.11.X.3576, MO085C11X6464D2, M.O085C.23.B.0004.D2, M.O085C.23.BX.0004.D2, M.O053C.7I.F.0053.D2, M.O053C.8D.S.0001.D2, M.O053C.8I.S.0009.D2, M.O053C.8I.S.0009.D2", ", ")
        
    Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With regEx
        For i = 0 To UBound(Inputstr)
            tbSøkProsjekt.Value = Inputstr(i)
            SStr = ""
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = True
            .pattern = "(\d[0-9a-zA-Z])\.?([a-zA-Z])\.?(\d{4})"
            If .test(Inputstr(i)) Then
                WBSParts = Split(.Execute(Inputstr(i)).Item(0).Value, ".")
                If UBound(WBSParts) > 0 Then
                    SStr = WBSParts(0) & "." & WBSParts(1) & "." & WBSParts(2)
                End If
                Debug.Print Inputstr(i) & ": " & SStr
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Set regEx = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Works for me, the one that doesn't is `M.O085C.23.BX.0004.D2`. `(\d{2})\.?([a-zA-Z])\.?(\d{4})` includes `(\d{2})([a-zA-Z])(\d{4})` since the dots are optional. Try `.Pattern = "(\d[0-9a-zA-Z])\.?([a-zA-Z])\.?(\d{4})"`

Comment: If you have `Set m = regex.Execute(string)` the first match is `m(0)`

Comment: For the examples "12B4321" and i.e. "MO085C12B4321D2", how do I get it in a form of "12.B.4321" using VBA?
I tried to use WBSParts = Split(.Execute(Inputstr(i)).Item(0).Value, "."), but  this only work when the (dot) are included...

Comment: @Reezer Can you please add the code that you are using to the question so readers have a complete overview?

Answer (score 2):

Join the submatches with dots to get 12.B.4321.

```vb
Private Sub WBStest()

    Dim regEx As Object, WBSParts, Inputstr() As String
    Dim s As String, i As Long
    
    Inputstr = Split("12X4321, 13.X.6945, M.O085C.11.X.3576, MO085C11X6464D2, " & _
        "M.O085C.23.B.0004.D2, M.O085C.23.BX.0004.D2, M.O053C.7I.F.0053.D2, " & _
        "M.O053C.8D.S.0001.D2, M.O053C.8I.S.0009.D2, M.O053C.8I.S.0009.D2", ", ")
    
    Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With regEx
        .Global = False
        .MultiLine = False
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "(\d[0-9A-Z])\.?([A-Z])\.?(\d{4})"

        For i = 0 To UBound(Inputstr)
            s = Trim(Inputstr(i))
            If .test(s) Then
                Set WBSParts = .Execute(s)(0).submatches
                Debug.Print s, WBSParts(0) & "." & WBSParts(1) & "." & WBSParts(2)
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Set regEx = Nothing

End Sub
```